# Sorting data using ORDER BY Clause in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two type of deal in my form `1)One way relocation deal and 2)Regular deal`.There is a table in my db -Vehicles.

```
vehicles table
=====================================================
id, pickuplocation, returnlocation, included location
```

Now when user choose `One way relocation deal` then in db, only `id,pickuplocation,returnlocation` will be inserted and the coloumn `included location` will be null. And when user choose `Regular deal`,the column `pickuplocation,returnlocation` wil be null only the coloumn `id and included location` will set.Problem is i want to sort the whole data using their location.I tried this query -

```
SELECT * 
FROM vehicles 
where 1=1 
ORDER BY pickuplocation ASC,returnlocation ASC
```

But it will not giving proper result because some data having null in included location.how can i sort for all `pickuplocation,returnlocation,exculded location`

Comment: WHere do you want the null entries to appear?

Comment: do you want `pickuplocation`, `returnlocation`, and `excluded location` to be in one column and sorted? how do you want to handle `null`?

Comment: What's the content of $condition? Why did you put a `1=1` condition?

Comment: Can you please give us the result and your expected result?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.I used this query

```
(SELECT id,pickuplocation,returnlocation,deal_type FROM `vehicles` where deal_type = 1)

UNION

(SELECT id,included_location,excluded_location,deal_type FROM `vehicles`  where deal_type = 2)

order by pickuplocation,returnlocation
```

I hope this will help someone who may run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: No, this won't help anyone in the future. "Why?" you ask, because we have little to no idea about the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `IFNULL` function

Try sorting by

```
 IFNULL(returnlocation, includedlocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM vehicles 
where 1=1 AND ($condition) 
ORDER BY pickuplocation ASC,returnlocation ASC
```

Assuming `$condition` will be something like `field01=1` OR `field2 >=1`